# Flex Async Madness - Any way to wait for a rpc.Responder to get a response before going to the next statement?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I feel like I must be doing this wrong.  I've got a function that is supposed to construct a query based on an API's description of available fields.  Here's what I've got:

```
var query_fields = getQueryFieldsFor(sobject_name);
// Need query fields for the next statement, which actually does the query
```

---

```
public function getQueryFieldsFor(sObject:String):String{
    //helper function to get queryfields for given sobject
    var queryFields:String = '';

    app.connection.describeSObject(sObject,
        new mx.rpc.Responder(
            function(result:DescribeSObjectResult):void{
                var returnFields:String = '';
                for ( var field:Field in result.fields ){
                    if(field.active){
                        returnFields.concat(field.name+',')
                    }
                }
             returnFields.slice(0, returnFields.length-1); //remove last comma
             queryFields = returnFields;
        }, function(error):void{
            Alert.show('error in getQueryFieldsFor function');
        })
     );

     return queryFields;
}
```

I know this doesn't work, and I think I understand why.  However, I keep running into this type of issue and I believe I'm just thinking about it/designing it wrong.  So what's a better pattern here?  Would really appreciate any insight on this.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `app.connection.describeSObject`?

Comment: It's a call for the salesforce.com API, given a s[alesforce]Object name (such as "Account"), it returns a bunch of different data about that object's properties, including a fields property which is an Array of Field objects.

Comment: I would argue that the thing you want to achieve is Flex Sync Madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to externalize your functions and execute your next line of code after the fact:

```
public function getQueryFieldsFor(sObject:String):String
{
    var responder:Responder = new Responder( onResult, onFault);
    app.connection.describeSObject(sObject, responder);
}

private function onResult(result:DescribeSObjectResult):void
{
        var returnFields:String = '';
        for ( var field:Field in result.fields ){
            if(field.active){
                returnFields.concat(field.name+',')
            }
        }
     returnFields.slice(0, returnFields.length-1); //remove last comma
     queryFields = returnFields;
}
```

Your main problem though is not the code, but a lack of thinking asynchronously.  You cannot have a function called "getQueryFields" that will return it instantly.  What you want to do is think in the request/response way.  You're trying to get some data, a request is made to a service, gets the data back, updates a property which is then binded to a view which gets redrawn.  This is the proper way to do any webapp.

It might be beneficial for you to also look at application frameworks like [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) and [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/download.php) since it helps you manage these situations.  Parsley also has a task library which lets you perform several asynchronous task one after another.